# How to wrap cordova getAppVersion on a variable promise?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this code:

```
var promiseVersionNumber;
            if (typeof cordova !== 'undefined') {
                console.log("I have cordova, I will try to get the AppversionNumeber");
                promiseVersionNumber = cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber();
            } else {
                console.warn("There is no cordova, I will use a dummyAppVersion");
                promiseVersionNumber = $q.when(dummyAppVersion);
            }

            return $q.when(
                (promiseVersionNumber).then(function(versionNumber){
                    defaultConfig.version = versionNumber;
                    return dbAppInfo.put(defaultConfig);
                }).then(function(putDefaultConfig){
                console.log("appConfig was created and saved on Database");

                return dbAppInfo.put({
                    _id: 'myLastUpdate',
                    myLastUpdate: today,
                    debug: todayDebug
                });
               }).catch(function(error){
                console.error("There was an error while initAppConfig appConfig on Database");
                console.dir(error);
                console.groupEnd("initAppConfig");
                return error;
            }));
```

In browser with my dummy `promiseVersionNumber` all works ok, but on device I get this error:

> TypeError: promiseVersionNumber.then(...).then(...).then(...).catch is not a function

How can I correctly wrap `cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use ngCordova, that would be the easy way. http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/appVersion/

Comment: Looking at ngCordova [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/blob/master/src/plugins/appVersion.js) , could it be that `cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber()` does not return a promise but just a plain object?

Comment: no they do return promises...       getVersionNumber: function () {
        var q = $q.defer();
        cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (version) {
          q.resolve(version);
        });

        return q.promise;
      },

Comment: I mean without the ngCordova wrapper. (Just to be safe I will use ngCordova)

Comment: oh. yes. I looks like it just takes a callback as argument... anyways 'converting' that to a promise is basically what ngCordova does..